# How can I use npm request module with bluebird in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, bluebird

webCheck.js

```
var request = require("request");
var Promise = require("bluebird");



module.exports = {
    check : function(address){
        var length;
        request(address).on('response',function(response){
        response.on('data',function(data){
            length = data.length;
            console.log("in : ",length); //  
        })
    });
    console.log("out : ",length);
    return length;
}
}
```

main.js

```
var webCheck = require('./webCheck.js');

    module.exports = {
    run : function(){
        console.log("result : ",webCheck.check("http://localhost:3000/status"));
        ...
```

Terminal

```
out :  undefined
result :  undefined
in : 821
```

I want to check the length of the website. However, the function that checks the website is not synchronous.
I want to return length after the request has been completed.

How can I do? I want to use bluebird module.

Comment: Welcome @sycoding! It can be difficult to make the `request` library work with promises. Is there any way for you to use [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise) in its place? This library was written as a complement to `promise`, has a very similar API, and is designed specifically for working with Bluebird promises.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the `request` module with bluebird promises, the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait) suggests to install `request-promise`. So after installing `request`, also `npm install request-promise`.

Then you have to make sure the `check` function returns this promise, so the caller can wait for it's result:

```
var request = require("request-promise");

module.exports = {
    check : function(address) {
        return request(address)
            .on('response', function(response) {
                return response;
            });
    }
}
```

Finally, the call in the main.js needs to wait for the promise to resolve, before the result can be used:

```
var webCheck = require('./webCheck.js');

module.exports = {
    run : function() {
        webCheck.check("http://localhost:3000/status").then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
    ...
}
```